# How to get access to Wix DB - Blog Posts

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs, velo

So right now I have a homepage, made by using html.
I want to add some divs, where I show the newest blogs I posted on my WIX page.

```
<div layout="row" layout-align="center center">
   <md-card flex="60" class="pad-md md-body-1 border-1" md-colors="{&quot;borderColor&quot;: &quot;epprimary1-500&quot;, &quot;color&quot;: &quot;epsecondary6&quot;}">
      {{blog headline}}
      <a href="{{blog link}}">Open Blog<md-icon>open_in_new</md-icon></a>
   </md-card>
</div>
```

On the Wix platform, I know where they store the data in a so called dataset:

[image: Wix Dataset]

Now I need to know how to access these data from my other website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out, finally!!

You can get the data you need via an http request.
Therefore, first of all, you need to add a javascript in your backend folder in Wix and name it "http-functions.js", delete it's content and add the folowing code.

Note: get_blogEntry() is **method**_**functionName**()

Blog/Posts is the DB I used, you can use any DB you have on wix.

```
import {ok, notFound, serverError} from 'wix-http-functions';
import wixData from 'wix-data';
export function get_blogEntry() {
  let options = {
    "headers": {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"
    }
  };
// query a collection to find matching items
return wixData.query("Blog/Posts")
.find()
.then( (results) => {
  // matching items were found
  if(results.items.length > 0) {
    let itemOne = results.items[0];
    let itemTwo = results.items[1];

    options.body = {
        "blogOneTitle": itemOne.title,
        "blogOneUrl": "https://etaplus.energy" + itemOne.postPageUrl,
        "blogTwoTitle": itemTwo.title,
        "blogTwoUrl": "https://etaplus.energy" + itemTwo.postPageUrl
    }
    return ok(options);
  }
})
// something went wrong
.catch( (error) => {
  options.body = {
    "error": error
  };
  return serverError(options);
} );
}
```

After you added this code in your backend, then you can access the data via the following URL:

"https://YOURWEBSITEURL/_functions/blogEntry**or whatever your function name is**"